# xpath ignore node

Tags: html, xpath

I'm looking for a way to select a node in xpath, giving that a node on it's path may exist or not. Just like '?' works in regexp ;)

For instance, I'd like to figure out a xpath query to get to `<td>` regardless of the case whether `<tbody>` node exists or not, with something like `/table/(tbody)?/tr/td`. I'd like it to work in both cases:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td />
 </tr>
</table>
```

and

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td />
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

This may fail to cover more complex cases, but in this example using `/table/tbody/tr/td | /table/tr/td` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
//table/descendant::tr/td
```

or

```
//table//tr/td
```

depending on your taste. The double slash is a "look that up somewhere on this level or deeper" (more formally, `descendant-or-self::` axis). [The spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) is, surprisingly, a very good read on this!